# sql developer how to filter date

Tags: sql, oracle

Peace
I have a table full of values and I need to filter all the dates of each month 10
That is to delete everyone who is between 10-01-2022 TO 10-31-2022

And not a specific date as I presented

```
    create table content(
    cname varchar2(1),
    type varchar2(15),
    episodes number,
    country varchar2(15),
    language varchar2(15),
    releasedate date,
     primary key(cname, type));
    
    insert into content values('A','film', 1, 'China', 'Mandarin', '03/10/2022');
    insert into content values('B','film', 1, 'Taiwan', 'Cantonese', '30/10/2022');
    insert into content values('C','film', 1, 'Singapore', 'Malay', '15/09/2022');
    insert into content values('A','series', 8, 'Korea', 'Korean', '28/09/2022');
    insert into content values('B','series', 10, 'China', 'Mandarin', '03/10/2022');
    insert into content values('C','series', 18, 'Korea', 'Korean', '01/11/2022');
    insert into content values('D','series', 8, 'Korea', 'Korean', '16/09/2022');
    insert into content values('D','documentary', 3, 'China', 'Mandarin', '18/10/2022');
    insert into content values('E','documentary', 6, 'Taiwan', 'Mandarin', '17/10/2022');
    
    
SELECT cname,type,country,episodes,language,releasedate
FROM content
minus
SELECT cname,type,country,episodes,language,releasedate
FROM content
WHERE  content.country ='China'
AND
content.TYPE ='documentary'
AND
content.MONTH(releasedate) =10;
```

Answer (score 0):

If is intended to fetch all data of October without checking the year, we can use `EXTRACT`, see here the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions059.htm#SQLRF00639)

```
SELECT cname, type, country, episodes, language, releasedate
FROM content
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM releasedate) = 10;
```

Otherwise, if only the October 2022 should be considered, we will prefer to use `BETWEEN` rather than two times `EXTRACT` for both year and month.

```
SELECT cname, type, country, episodes, language, releasedate
FROM content
WHERE releasedate BETWEEN 
TO_DATE('2022-10-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND 
TO_DATE('2022-10-31','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

If your dates can contain a time, we should add a `TRUNC` to avoid a date like '10/31/2022 12:22:22' will not be found:

```
SELECT cname, type, country, episodes, language, releasedate
FROM content
WHERE TRUNC(releasedate) BETWEEN 
TO_DATE('2022-10-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND 
TO_DATE('2022-10-31','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Here we can verify this is working correctly: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jqthaTn-)

Comment: I re-edited the post with the changes and it doesn't work

Comment: @dereyyovel I added a fiddle in my answer which shows it's working correctly. Please try out and verify this. If you think there is something wrong, please edit the fiddle (or create a new one if you prefer this) to show what's incorrect and share the link here.

Answer (score 0):

Change from:

```sql
SELECT ...
MINUS
SELECT ... WHERE X AND Y AND Z
```

to a single query:

```sql
SELECT ...
WHERE NOT X OR NOT Y OR NOT Z
```

Which for your query would be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   content
WHERE  country != 'China'
OR     type    != 'documentary'
OR     releasedate <  DATE '2022-10-01'
OR     releasedate >= DATE '2022-11-01';
```

or, if you can have `NULL` values:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   content
WHERE  country != 'China'
OR     country IS NULL
OR     type    != 'documentary'
OR     type    IS NULL
OR     releasedate <  DATE '2022-10-01'
OR     releasedate >= DATE '2022-11-01'
OR     releasedate IS NULL;
```

---

If you want to always exclude that month then use a mix of `AND` and `OR`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   content
WHERE  (  country != 'China'
       OR type    != 'documentary' )
AND    (  releasedate <  DATE '2022-10-01'
       OR releasedate >= DATE '2022-11-01' );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pHY2SqNq)